# code completion for liftweb scala in intellij idea

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, lift, code-completion

I'm working with a Scala application using Intellij Idea 13.1.1 community edition. Although i am able to compile and run my application, but the IDE shows error in editor window as it cannot resolve the class. How can i remove that and enable code completion feature for Scala and Liftweb?

Comment: How did you import the project into IntelliJ? Which class(es) are unable to resolve?

Comment: File > Import Project > Then Selected the project > Create Project from existing source. Did you mean this?
All classes of scala and liftweb are unable to resolve.
Previously I had used NetBeans. In Netbeans when we import api libraries(jars) we need not worry about code completion. How is it done in IntellIJ?

Comment: Do you have the Scala plugin installed? With it, IntelliJ should recognize sbt files in the import file browser.

Comment: yes i do. Do we need to import libraries or jars?

Comment: No, not individually.  Use _File_ -> _Close Project_ then reimport by selecting the `build.sbt` file in the file chooser popup.

Answer (score 1):

Now I found the solution thanks to joescii. While importing a project import using build.sbt